# Node Error: Cannot find module - typescript api for custom module where I export mongoose schemas and interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, node-modules

I have a typescript module [@tlabs/models](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tlabs/models) where I'm simply exporting in index.ts:

```
export * from '../models......'
```

where in each file I have something like:

```
export const Project = typedModel('projects', ProjectSchema);
```

and my only dependency is `ts-mongoose` imported in each file simply as:

```
import { createSchema, Type, typedModel, ExtractProps } from 'ts-mongoose';
```

ts-mongoose being a dependency that itself required mongoose + mongoose types.

In my typescript node project I have `ts-mongoose`, `mongoose` and @tlabs/models as dependencies and `@types/mongoose` as dev dependency.

Running tsc is fine, the files get compiled and there's no error being thrown out but then trying to run the actual files throws out:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@tlabs/models'
```

I have reinstalled all modules several times and checked package.json as well as the actual files on the disk + through vscode and they're right there.

What am I missing out?

My tsconfig is:

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./node_modules", "./node_modules/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [],
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final TS config for my exported models:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

and relevant package.json configuration:

```
{
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "types": "lib",
    "scripts": {
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "build": "tsc -p ."
    },
    "files": [
        "lib"
    ],
}
```